# C++ Comparing two char arrays and returning -1,0,1

Tags: c++

This was the prompt -

searchForAccount() - This method should take one parameter: a character array containing the account number code of the CreditAccount to search for (searchNumber). The method should return an integer.

The logic for this method is a variation of the binary search of a sorted list strategy.

As usual, you'll need to use strcmp() to perform the comparison of account numbers.

I'm not exactly sure what I'm being asked to do to be honest. I am from Java and the instructor described it like a thisString.Compareto(anotherString) which returns -1,0,1.

This is my attempt

```
int AccountDB::searchForAccount(char searchNum[])
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = numAccounts - 1;
    int mid;
    while (low <= high)
    {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;
        if(strcmp(searchNum, accSet[mid].getAccountNumber()) == 0)
        return mid;
    }
        if(strcmp(searchNum, accSet[mid].getAccountNumber()) > 0)
            high = mid - 1;
    else
            low = mid + 1;
return -1;
}
```

does this look correct?

Comment: Devise some tests for it. Test it.

Comment: And no, it is not going to work. You will never get out of your loop, as the two variables that are used for the condition never change.

Comment: If you're unclear about what your assignment is, ask your instructor to explain it to you. They gave it to you, so they should know what they want you to do better than we would.

Comment: You do not change `high` and `low` in your while loop; therefore, the while loop will run infinitely.

Comment: Run infinitely. Hah! Kill task. Hmmm. Anyone know what the error message "I'm afraid I can't let you do that, Dave." means?